# How to Receive and capture packets from internet/remote host using DPDK?

Tags: packet-sniffers, packet-capture, dpdk

I want to capture Raw Packets from any host and capture them in a file like "recieved.pcap" bypassing the kernel.
I am using a virtual ec2 instace for this.
To bypass kernel I have set up DPDK on my instance.
I am new to networking and any help would be appreciated !

I have:

1. DPDK version: 19.11.5 installed on Amazon Linux 2 ec2 instance.
2. NIC binded to DPDK : Amazon eni
3. I have libpcap-dev installed.

I ran testpmd application ,and here is the output :

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-82-187 app]$ sudo ./testpmd -l 0-3 -n 4 -- -i
EAL: Detected 8 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: PCI device 0000:00:05.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 1d0f:ec20 net_ena
EAL: PCI device 0000:00:06.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 1d0f:ec20 net_ena
Interactive-mode selected
testpmd: create a new mbuf pool <mbuf_pool_socket_0>: n=171456, size=2176, socket=0
testpmd: preferred mempool ops selected: ring_mp_mc

Warning! port-topology=paired and odd forward ports number, the last port will pair with itself.

Configuring Port 0 (socket 0)
Port 0: 16:61:BE:67:49:75
Checking link statuses...
Done
Error during enabling promiscuous mode for port 0: Operation not supported - ignore
```

Comment: please share the following information `1) dpdk version intending to use, 2) NIC details for DPDK 3) do you have libpcap-dev installed or not`. Based on the answers it will be much easier to point to the easiest solution

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! I updated the details.

Comment: assuming you are using either `0000:00:05.0` or `0000:00:06.0` is your WAN port, then you 2 options, First option is use tap interface while enable DPDK PDUMP to capture the packets. Second option is use NIC port and tap PMD to create passing of packets to and fro kernel without interupting while capturing. Hence can you rephrase what is that you are trying to achieve (do you want packets to go into kernel)?

Comment: You can only capture the packets destined to your host, not any other Internet packets.

Comment: @RonMaupin one can create a virtual pipeline (intercept) with 2 nic port and capture just like SNORT Suricata or BRO (IDS). So I humbly disagree to the `You can only capture the packets destined to your host, not any other Internet packets.`

Comment: @VipinVarghese I don't want packets to go in kernel. So is first option recommended for me? can you tell me how can I tap my interface here and should I have at least two ports binded to DPDK ? (currently '0000:00:06.0' is binded with DPDK).  Sorry for sounding noob here, I am trying to learn DPDK.

Comment: @RonMaupin I don't want to capture any random internet packets, but i want to hit DPDK with remote host and capture raw packets (without letting them go into kernel)

Comment: @chandanXty updated with the answer based on your comments, please go through the same and try it out (it works locally) for me. Happy to help in debug too.

Comment: @chandanXty please set up a debug call if you facing issue with dpdk pdump

Comment: @VipinVarghese First of all Thanks for the help! ,I am using testpmd in forwarding mode I am able to run pdump fine, 'tx.pcap' is also generating with udp packets in it. But I am stuck as I want to capture the packets which comes from another remote host(assuming I set up a php server on my instance and I hit this server from remote) what connections should I do To make it work. How can I reach out to you for debug call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the intercept scenario, there are 4 options to solve this problem

1. Option-1: for Remote Termination use of single DPDK port with MAC|VLAN address modification.
2. Option-2: for Remote Termination use of two DPDK port with no MAC address modification.
3. Option-3: for Local Termination use of DPDK TAP PMD to terminate to HOST/GUEST OS, with no packet MAC|VLAN modification.
4. Option-4: for Local Termination use of DPDK PCAP PMD to intercept the packets from Kernel interface, with no packet MAC|VLAN modification.

Please follow the steps to capture the traffic appropriately. For

Option-1:

1. Create the VM with 1 DPDK port.
2. Use testpmd or sample application l2fwd (modified with DPDK rte_pdump_init) to capture and replay back into PORT.
3. Since MAC-address|VLAN is modified with appropriate rules one can forward from remote HOST to desired destination
4. Start dpdk PDUMP application, example `sudo ./build/app/dpdk-pdump -- --pdump 'port=0,queue=*,tx-dev=./tx.pcap'` . This will capture packets that enter from outside and write into ***tx.pcap***.

Option-2:

1. Create VM with 2 DPDK ports
2. Start DPDK modified application (use dpdk rte_pdump_init) either skeleton or l2fwd.
3. for l2fwd use option **--no-mac-updating**.
4. Start dpdk PDUMP application, example `sudo ./build/app/dpdk-pdump -- --pdump 'port=0,queue=*,tx-dev=./tx.pcap'` . This will capture packets that enter from outside and write into ***tx.pcap***

Option-3:

1. Create the VM with 1 DPDK port (AMAZON enic)
2. bind the desired DPDK port (WAN) with appropriate UIO driver
3. Start DPDK application like basicfwd `sudo ./build/basicfwd -l 2 --vdev=net_tap0,mac="mac address of DPDK port" -a <PCIe BDF>`.
4. Within linux terminal `sudo ifconfig dtap0 <ip address/mask> up`
5. [optional] add desired route entry.
6. use linux tcpdump, python or any packet capture application to grab packets from dtap0 interface for RX|TX or both direction.

Option-4:

1. Create the VM with 1 DPDK port (AMAZON enic)
2. make sure the interface is bind with kernel driver.
3. ensure the interface is able to reach outside network (WAN) using `ping -I <interface name> stackoverflow.com`
4. run dpdk modified application like basicfwd or l2fwd with rte_pdump_init (example `./build/l2fwd -l 2 --vdev=net_pcap0,iface=<interface name> -- -p 1 -T 1 --no-mac-updating`)
5. capture the packets using DPDK PDUMP applciation. example: `sudo ./build/app/dpdk-pdump -- --pdump 'port=0,queue=*,tx-dev=./tx.pcap'`

Note:

- refer [for use DPDK PDUMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62795017/dpdk-pdump-failed-to-hotplug-add-device) use case.
- recommendation is use `option 3`, as it eliminates the need for DPDK secondary process and disabling ASLR.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am following option 1 with only one port in Amazon ec2:
 How to perform step 3 ? I mean where should be these MAC-Address|VLAN changes be made? 
Also i want to capture the packets by hitting a server on ec2 instance (like from other host via url). So how should I create server so that DPDK NIC can capture it?

Comment: as mentioned in step 2 and step 3 `modified with DPDK rte_pdump_init`, one needs to modify to do so (l2fwd modfies the MAC to 02:00:00:00:0X where X is port number).

Comment: Thankyou! for the detailed answer!