# Multiple errors when trying to use DPDK pdump

Tags: dpdk

Goal: To write a DPDK based application that can read UDP packets via a 100gbe ethernet port and write the payload to disk depending on what the destination IP/Port is. At most, each 100gbe link will have two different destination IP addresses and 4 unique destination port numbers. Initial design calls for two unique port numbers.

### Hardware

#### Current Test System

For now, I am testing with the following hardware. The server hardware and NVME drives will be significantly upgraded in the next few weeks. For now, I am using the following hardware to develop a proof of concept (POC). The NIC will remain the same unless recommended otherwise.

- 2 x Intel Xeon Gold 6348 CPU @ 2.6 Ghz

  - 28 cores per socket
  - Max 3.5 Ghz
  - Hyperthreading disabled
  - Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
  - Kernel 5.15.0-53-generic
  - Cores set to performance governor
  - 4 x Sabrent 2TB Rocket 4 Plus in RAID0 Config
  - 128 GB DDR4 Memory
  - 10 1GB HugePages (Can change to what is required)
- 1 x Mellanox ConnectX-5 100gbe NIC

  - `31:00.0 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27800 Family [ConnectX-5]`
  - Firmware-version: 16.35.1012
- UDP Source:

  - 100 gbe NIC
  - 9000 MTU Packets
  - ipv4-udp packets
  - Currently only 4GB/s per port but eventually will be 10GB/s per port.

#### NIC Information

ethtool output:

```
Settings for ens7f0np0:
        Supported ports: [ Backplane ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseKX/Full
                                10000baseKR/Full
                                40000baseKR4/Full
                                40000baseCR4/Full
                                40000baseSR4/Full
                                40000baseLR4/Full
                                25000baseCR/Full
                                25000baseKR/Full
                                25000baseSR/Full
                                50000baseCR2/Full
                                50000baseKR2/Full
                                100000baseKR4/Full
                                100000baseSR4/Full
                                100000baseCR4/Full
                                100000baseLR4_ER4/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: None        RS      BASER
        Advertised link modes:  1000baseKX/Full
                                10000baseKR/Full
                                40000baseKR4/Full
                                40000baseCR4/Full
                                40000baseSR4/Full
                                40000baseLR4/Full
                                25000baseCR/Full
                                25000baseKR/Full
                                25000baseSR/Full
                                50000baseCR2/Full
                                50000baseKR2/Full
                                100000baseKR4/Full
                                100000baseSR4/Full
                                100000baseCR4/Full
                                100000baseLR4_ER4/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: RS
        Speed: 100000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Port: Direct Attach Copper
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Supports Wake-on: d
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000004 (4)
                               link
        Link detected: yes
```

testpmd info:

```
[sudo] password for maa: 
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 56
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 2
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: No available 2048 kB hugepages reported
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1017) device: 0000:31:00.0 (socket 0)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1017) device: 0000:31:00.1 (socket 0)
TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
Interactive-mode selected
testpmd: create a new mbuf pool <mb_pool_0>: n=171456, size=2176, socket=0
testpmd: preferred mempool ops selected: ring_mp_mc
Configuring Port 0 (socket 0)
Port 0: B8:CE:F6:FB:13:30
Configuring Port 1 (socket 0)
Port 1: B8:CE:F6:FB:13:31
Checking link statuses...
Done
testpmd> show port info 0

********************* Infos for port 0  *********************
MAC address: B8:CE:F6:FB:13:30
Device name: 31:00.0
Driver name: mlx5_pci
Firmware-version: 16.35.1012
Devargs: 
Connect to socket: 0
memory allocation on the socket: 0
Link status: up
Link speed: 100 Gbps
Link duplex: full-duplex
Autoneg status: On
MTU: 1500
Promiscuous mode: enabled
Allmulticast mode: disabled
Maximum number of MAC addresses: 128
Maximum number of MAC addresses of hash filtering: 0
VLAN offload: 
  strip off, filter off, extend off, qinq strip off
Hash key size in bytes: 40
Redirection table size: 1
Supported RSS offload flow types:
  ipv4
  ipv4-frag
  ipv4-tcp
  ipv4-udp
  ipv4-other
  ipv6
  ipv6-frag
  ipv6-tcp
  ipv6-udp
  ipv6-other
  ipv6-ex
  ipv6-tcp-ex
  ipv6-udp-ex
  l4-dst-only
  l4-src-only
  l3-dst-only
  l3-src-only
Minimum size of RX buffer: 32
Maximum configurable length of RX packet: 65536
Maximum configurable size of LRO aggregated packet: 65280
Current number of RX queues: 1
Max possible RX queues: 1024
Max possible number of RXDs per queue: 65535
Min possible number of RXDs per queue: 0
RXDs number alignment: 1
Current number of TX queues: 1
Max possible TX queues: 1024
Max possible number of TXDs per queue: 65535
Min possible number of TXDs per queue: 0
TXDs number alignment: 1
Max segment number per packet: 40
Max segment number per MTU/TSO: 40
Device capabilities: 0x14( RXQ_SHARE FLOW_SHARED_OBJECT_KEEP )
Switch name: 31:00.0
Switch domain Id: 0
Switch Port Id: 65535
Switch Rx domain: 0
```

RX offload capabilities:

```
testpmd> show port 0 rx_offload capabilities
Rx Offloading Capabilities of port 0 :
  Per Queue : VLAN_STRIP IPV4_CKSUM UDP_CKSUM TCP_CKSUM TCP_LRO SCATTER TIMESTAMP KEEP_CRC RSS_HASH BUFFER_SPLIT
  Per Port  : VLAN_FILTER
```

#### Physical Layout

[image: ![[Pasted image 20221129100245.png]]]

For now, I am only attempting to get a single stream on a single port working. My plan is for each queue to be tied to an lcore, and each lcore has its own thread to strip the headers, and then a thread to write to disk. Assume that the hardware is on the same NUMA node. No TX is currently required.

#### Requirements

- Eventually 10 GB/s to disk from one 100gb/s port (Currently trying to get 4GB/s)

  - Assume that I will have a processor, PCI Lanes, and NVME configuration that can support this, I am only worried about the DPDK side of things for now.
  - Each individual stream will be ~5GB/s, currently they are ~2GB/s and I am just trying to get that to work for now.
  - Each stream's headers are stripped.
  - Each stream has its payload written to disk as a single continous file (.dat format).
  - Each stream has a unique port number.
  - If the FCS is bad, drop the packet and replace with blank data (all zeros).

#### What I have tried:

I am having a similar issue to the poster at this question: [DPDK pdump failed to hotplug add device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62795017/dpdk-pdump-failed-to-hotplug-add-device)
I attempted the fix there and am still having issues.

I have simply tried to get a pcap file by attaching pdump to the skeleton code.

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
 * Copyright(c) 2010-2015 Intel Corporation
 */

#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <rte_eal.h>
#include <rte_ethdev.h>
#include <rte_cycles.h>
#include <rte_lcore.h>
#include <rte_mbuf.h>
#include <rte_pdump.h>

#define RX_RING_SIZE 1024
#define TX_RING_SIZE 1024

#define NUM_MBUFS 8191
#define MBUF_CACHE_SIZE 250
#define BURST_SIZE 32

/* basicfwd.c: Basic DPDK skeleton forwarding example. */

/*
 * Initializes a given port using global settings and with the RX buffers
 * coming from the mbuf_pool passed as a parameter.
 */

/* Main functional part of port initialization. 8< */
static inline int
port_init(uint16_t port, struct rte_mempool *mbuf_pool)
{
    struct rte_eth_conf port_conf;
    const uint16_t rx_rings = 1, tx_rings = 1;
    uint16_t nb_rxd = RX_RING_SIZE;
    uint16_t nb_txd = TX_RING_SIZE;
    int retval;
    uint16_t q;
    struct rte_eth_dev_info dev_info;
    struct rte_eth_txconf txconf;

    if (!rte_eth_dev_is_valid_port(port))
        return -1;

    memset(&port_conf, 0, sizeof(struct rte_eth_conf));

    retval = rte_eth_dev_info_get(port, &dev_info);
    if (retval != 0) {
        printf("Error during getting device (port %u) info: %s\n",
                port, strerror(-retval));
        return retval;
    }

    if (dev_info.tx_offload_capa & RTE_ETH_TX_OFFLOAD_MBUF_FAST_FREE)
        port_conf.txmode.offloads |=
            RTE_ETH_TX_OFFLOAD_MBUF_FAST_FREE;

    /* Configure the Ethernet device. */
    retval = rte_eth_dev_configure(port, rx_rings, tx_rings, &port_conf);
    if (retval != 0)
        return retval;

    retval = rte_eth_dev_adjust_nb_rx_tx_desc(port, &nb_rxd, &nb_txd);
    if (retval != 0)
        return retval;

    /* Allocate and set up 1 RX queue per Ethernet port. */
    for (q = 0; q < rx_rings; q++) {
        retval = rte_eth_rx_queue_setup(port, q, nb_rxd,
                rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port), NULL, mbuf_pool);
        if (retval < 0)
            return retval;
    }

    txconf = dev_info.default_txconf;
    txconf.offloads = port_conf.txmode.offloads;
    /* Allocate and set up 1 TX queue per Ethernet port. */
    for (q = 0; q < tx_rings; q++) {
        retval = rte_eth_tx_queue_setup(port, q, nb_txd,
                rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port), &txconf);
        if (retval < 0)
            return retval;
    }

    /* Starting Ethernet port. 8< */
    retval = rte_eth_dev_start(port);
    /* >8 End of starting of ethernet port. */
    if (retval < 0)
        return retval;

    /* Display the port MAC address. */
    struct rte_ether_addr addr;
    retval = rte_eth_macaddr_get(port, &addr);
    if (retval != 0)
        return retval;

    printf("Port %u MAC: %02" PRIx8 " %02" PRIx8 " %02" PRIx8
               " %02" PRIx8 " %02" PRIx8 " %02" PRIx8 "\n",
            port, RTE_ETHER_ADDR_BYTES(&addr));

    /* Enable RX in promiscuous mode for the Ethernet device. */
    retval = rte_eth_promiscuous_enable(port);
    /* End of setting RX port in promiscuous mode. */
    if (retval != 0)
        return retval;

    return 0;
}
/* >8 End of main functional part of port initialization. */

/*
 * The lcore main. This is the main thread that does the work, reading from
 * an input port and writing to an output port.
 */

 /* Basic forwarding application lcore. 8< */
static __rte_noreturn void
lcore_main(void)
{
    uint16_t port;
    int total = 0;

    /*
     * Check that the port is on the same NUMA node as the polling thread
     * for best performance.
     */
    RTE_ETH_FOREACH_DEV(port)
        if (rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port) >= 0 &&
                rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port) !=
                        (int)rte_socket_id())
            printf("WARNING, port %u is on remote NUMA node to "
                    "polling thread.\n\tPerformance will "
                    "not be optimal.\n", port);

    printf("\nCore %u forwarding packets. [Ctrl+C to quit]\n",
            rte_lcore_id());

    /* Main work of application loop. 8< */
    for (;;) {
        /*
         * Receive packets on a port and forward them on the paired
         * port. The mapping is 0 -> 1, 1 -> 0, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2, etc.
         */
        RTE_ETH_FOREACH_DEV(port) {

            /* Get burst of RX packets, from first port of pair. */
            struct rte_mbuf *bufs[BURST_SIZE];
            const uint16_t nb_rx = rte_eth_rx_burst(port, 0,
                    bufs, BURST_SIZE);

            if (unlikely(nb_rx == 0))
                continue;

        
            total += nb_rx;
            
            //rte_pktmbuf_free(bufs);
            //printf("\nTotal: %d",total);
        }
    
    }
    
    /* >8 End of loop. */
}
/* >8 End Basic forwarding application lcore. */

/*
 * The main function, which does initialization and calls the per-lcore
 * functions.
 */
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct rte_mempool *mbuf_pool;
    unsigned nb_ports;
    uint16_t portid;

    /* Initializion the Environment Abstraction Layer (EAL). 8< */
    int ret = rte_eal_init(argc, argv);
    rte_pdump_init();
    if (ret < 0)
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Error with EAL initialization\n");
    /* >8 End of initialization the Environment Abstraction Layer (EAL). */

    argc -= ret;
    argv += ret;

    /* Check that there is an even number of ports to send/receive on. */
    nb_ports = rte_eth_dev_count_avail();
    // if (nb_ports < 2 || (nb_ports & 1))
    //  rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Error: number of ports must be even\n");

    /* Creates a new mempool in memory to hold the mbufs. */

    /* Allocates mempool to hold the mbufs. 8< */
    mbuf_pool = rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("MBUF_POOL", NUM_MBUFS * nb_ports,
        MBUF_CACHE_SIZE, 0, RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE, rte_socket_id());
    /* >8 End of allocating mempool to hold mbuf. */

    if (mbuf_pool == NULL)
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot create mbuf pool\n");

    /* Initializing all ports. 8< */
    RTE_ETH_FOREACH_DEV(portid)
        if (port_init(portid, mbuf_pool) != 0)
            rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot init port %"PRIu16 "\n",
                    portid);
    /* >8 End of initializing all ports. */

    if (rte_lcore_count() > 1)
        printf("\nWARNING: Too many lcores enabled. Only 1 used.\n");

    /* Call lcore_main on the main core only. Called on single lcore. 8< */
    lcore_main();
    /* >8 End of called on single lcore. */

    /* clean up the EAL */
    rte_eal_cleanup();
    rte_pdump_uninit();

    return 0;
}
```

Command to run this example that I am using: `sudo ./dpdk-skeleton -l 1,2,3,4 -n 4 -a 0000:31:00.0`

Command running:

```
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 56
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 2
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: No available 2048 kB hugepages reported
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1017) device: 0000:31:00.0 (socket 0)
TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
Port 0 MAC: b8 ce f6 fb 13 30

WARNING: Too many lcores enabled. Only 1 used.

Core 1 forwarding packets. [Ctrl+C to quit]
```

I am not really sure what some command line values should be (like -n) so I am just guessing at this point.

For pdump, I am using this command  `sudo ./dpdk-pdump -l 3,4,5 -a 0000:31:00.0 -- --multi --pdump 'port=0,queue=0,rx-dev=/mnt/md0/rx-1.pcap'`

Again I am not sure of some of these values so making a best guess.

**The Issue**
Now with the primary application running, I attempt to run pdump the first time:

```
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 56
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 2
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket_57567_26f06531cb8cd
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1017) device: 0000:31:00.0 (socket 0)
Segmentation fault
```

The Second Time:

```
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 56
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 2
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket_57601_26f14f88bf7bb
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1017) device: 0000:31:00.0 (socket 0)
EAL: Failed to hotplug add device
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
Cause: vdev creation failed:create_mp_ring_vdev:767
```

And finally, the third time seems to run but has an unfamiliar MAC address:

```
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 56
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 2
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket_57679_26f28a2a6e9f1
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1017) device: 0000:31:00.0 (socket 0)
Port 1 MAC: 02 70 63 61 70 01
 core (4); port 0 device ((null)) queue 0
```

However, I am not receiving anything and the pcap file is empty (and yes I am sending packets):

```
Signal 2 received, preparing to exit...
##### PDUMP DEBUG STATS #####
 -packets dequeued:                     0
 -packets transmitted to vdev:          0
 -packets freed:                        0
```

Also, on the second run, these messages start appearing on the primary application:

```
EAL: Failed to send hotplug request to secondary
6: [./dpdk-skeleton(_start+0x25) [0x55f70a909045]]
5: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7fb90e478e40]]
4: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) [0x7fb90e478d90]]
3: [./dpdk-skeleton(main+0x1ad) [0x55f70a20a8ad]]
2: [./dpdk-skeleton(+0x1fdde7) [0x55f70a014de7]]
1: [./dpdk-skeleton(rte_dump_stack+0x32) [0x55f70aa973d2]]
lcore 1 called rx_pkt_burst for not ready port 1
6: [./dpdk-skeleton(_start+0x25) [0x55f70a909045]]
5: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7fb90e478e40]]
4: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) [0x7fb90e478d90]]
3: [./dpdk-skeleton(main+0x1ad) [0x55f70a20a8ad]]
2: [./dpdk-skeleton(+0x1fdde7) [0x55f70a014de7]]
1: [./dpdk-skeleton(rte_dump_stack+0x32) [0x55f70aa973d2]]
lcore 1 called rx_pkt_burst for not ready port 1
6: [./dpdk-skeleton(_start+0x25) [0x55f70a909045]]
5: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7fb90e478e40]]
4: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) [0x7fb90e478d90]]
3: [./dpdk-skeleton(main+0x1ad) [0x55f70a20a8ad]]
2: [./dpdk-skeleton(+0x1fdde7) [0x55f70a014de7]]
1: [./dpdk-skeleton(rte_dump_stack+0x32) [0x55f70aa973d2]]
```

#### My Questions

I will handle writing to file etc. later. I am simply trying to get the data into DPDK properly and to the correct queue at this point.

1. I assume that I need to use RSS or rte_flow to direct each stream to its own queue based on IP/Port. How do I do this? This is my first time doing any kind of advanced network programming so I am not familiar with these concepts, but based on my research they appear to be what I need.
2. What is the difference between RSS and rte_flow/offloading? Are they the same thing?
3. Are there any examples out there that are similar to what I am trying to do?
4. Is what I am trying to do feasible?

Comment: you are asking multiple things in one question. So the request again is to bring clarity. Please answer the following for clarity, nic firmware, speed, number of queues enabled. Is RSS enabled? the reason for the request you are trying to capture from `queue 0` with multi-pdump enabled. You are defeating the purpose. So either enable your primary with 1 queue and capture with 1 queue, else enable cores with multi queue capture for multiple queue.

Comment: @VipinVarghese I cannot figure out how to enable queues or RSS. The NIC firmware is the latest Mellanox firmware for the card. The speed is 100000Mb/s. I am simply asking how I need to configure everything to get this to work. I will update my question with more details.

Comment: then your question and statment is wrong, as per your comment the issue is described for primary process, and your talking about DPDK pdump (secondary) process not capturing the packets. This gives a wrong notion, please rephrase and correct your real intention

Comment: @VipinVarghese Why is my question and statement wrong? I am simply asking why this is not working? I have modified the skeleton example to attach a secondary process (pdump) and nothing is being captured. Why? Thanks. I have added more information to the question.

Comment: @adstra your question `Multiple errors when trying to use DPDK pdump`, real intent is `primary is not workign with RSS` based on the comment, happy to have quick discussion and point you to right answers

Comment: @VipinVarghese I would appreciate a discussion in order to correct my misunderstandings.

Comment: pleae share meeting invite - google meet or zoom

Comment: @VipinVarghese going on vacation until next week. Let’s plan on meeting then.

Comment: @VipinVarghese after researching the question more, I have updated the issues above. How can I send you a link to meet? Email?

Comment: Feel free to email me at: tru3anomaly@proton.me

Comment: @VipinVarghese I would like to close this out, are you still able to assist? Thank you.

Comment: good to see you back from your break. will look into the same and update the answer too soon.

Comment: waiting for your meeting invite link for live debug on the crash you have mentioned

Comment: answer to your query is been shared, please go through the same and accpet|upvote to help others to find the right answer. Please note I have shared more than twice for live debug for your multiple seg fault too.

Comment: @VipinVarghese thank you for your answer.  I actually think the live debug is no longer needed after reading your answer, I see that the multiprocess model is not the way to go for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part of question:
If the goal to ***capture packets at line rate and write the descriptor and met-data into NVME***, then please do not use the testpmd-pdump model. this will not scale for your use case intent.

To clarify the above

1. DPDK allows a [multiprocess model](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/multi_proc_support.html) - Single primary and multiple secondary to share same hugepage, hw resources and NIC.
2. DPDK testpmd and dpdk pdump is a prime example of using priamry-secondary model
3. BUT PDUMP library as of today make use of huge page sharing to clone-copy the packet received from PRIMARY (testpmd) to send it over RING buffer to SECODNARY (PDUMP) and then write to file using PCAP
4. PDUMP application is enahced to support [multiple queues on multiple CPU](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides-16.07/sample_app_ug/pdump.html), but one will still have inherent overhead of packet copy and send over ring buffer.

hence for the above use case mentioned, best approach to have the Primary custom application to receive packets over multiple queues (4 streams - then 4 queues) for UDP. ***Take as much of help from HW (MLX NIC CX05) for packet filtering using rte_flow
based flow bifurcation and type for packet classification to minimize the CPU overhead in parsing***.

The second part of the question:

1. you are using DPDK Skeleton as primary
2. there is only 1RX-TX queue configured for the port.
3. due to the inherent design of CX-5 max that 1 queue can do is around 35Mpps to 40Mpps with 1 queue with the right settings.
4. for 100Gbps port with 1 queue you can achieve line rate for simple forward for a payload size of 512B onwards
5. From the code snippet I do find `rte_pdump_init` invoked but returned not checked (please fix).
6. I believe MLX CX-5 works with PDUMP with the right firmware, hence please cross-check the same too (information requested over comment).

But the recommendation is not to use PDUMP as secondary due to native overhead to MP_HANDLE. Instead directly consume the paylaod in primary or secondary.

Note:

1. as mentioned there are 3 or 4 scenarios cramped into a single question, and requires live debug for sorting these out 1 by 1.
2. please do not club multiple questions and scenario into 1 question